# Win32 How to detect that user has chosen small icons for taskbar?

Tags: winapi, hook, taskbar

I'm developing an application in C# which needs to detect when use changed icon size on the taskbar. I know how to check if small icons are enabled/disabled for the user (in registry) but how to detect the moment when user actually changes them?

Comment: There is no notification for that, apps should never care about it.

Comment: Can I ask why your app needs the value of an internal setting in an external application?

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% on this, but handling [`WM_SETTINGCHANGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725497%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) might do the trick here.

Comment: Great API! I didn't know this one exists! I didn't find anything regarding taskbar icons size unfortunately :(